# the meaning of the word "bearing" in a sentence

Tags: meaning

> The bearing of these ideas upon our thinking about the ancient world is immediately apparent when we state the broadest generalization that can be made about the structural relations of the region that is the subject of this volume.

The sentence above is from THE CAMBRIDGE ANCIENT HISTORY Volume 01 Part I, page 5.
I want to know the meaning of the word 'bearing'. I've referenced dictionary but I didn't find a meaning which could let me understand the sentence well. Anybody can help me?? OvO

PS: What I found in Longman dictionary of contemporary English 5ed is as follows:

bearing noun

1 have a/some/no etc bearing on something   to have an effect or influence on something, or not have any effect or influence:
Exercise has a direct bearing on how healthy you are.

2 lose your bearings
a) to become confused about where you are:
I completely lost my bearings in the dark.
b) to become confused about what you should do next:
young men who have lost their bearings in a changing society

3 get/find your bearings
a) to find out exactly where you are:
He paused to get his bearings.
b) to feel confident that you know what you should do next:
An introduction session helps new students get their bearings.

4 [singular, uncountable]   the way in which you move, stand, or behave, especially when this shows your character

5 [countable]   technical   a direction or angle that is shown by a compass:
learning to take    a compass   bearing

6 [countable]   technical   a part of a machine that turns on another part, or in which a turning part is held ➔    ball bearing

Comment: It means 'relevance' in that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Bearing* as used here is the gerund form of the verb *to bear*. As such, consider this entry:

> **bear** *v. intr*
>   2. To have relevance or influence; apply: *They studied how the relativity theory bears on the history of science.*

[[TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bear)]

So that part of the sentence could be rephrased as follows:

> The influence of these ideas upon our thinking about the ancient world . . .

Comment: Sense 9 of OED *bearing*, noun: “Tendency to exert influence, practical relation or reference to other things; aspect.”

Comment: Or, in a word, relevance (to)